# How can I scrape data from a table on a website using php

Tags: php, web-scraping

Still new to php programming and I have been trying to scrape data from a table in a website (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_EliteBook). Particularly getting elitebook laptops that use  intel graphics card but I am having issues going about the code to access the data in the element I want. If anyone could help me to an idea I would be grateful.

Been using the simplehtmldom.php and the foreach loop to try and access the td element of the table and print the result but all I get are a variety of errors. Attached is the code I am currently trying

```php
<?php

include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_EliteBook');

$table= $html->find('table[class="wikitable"]',1);

//$tdata= array();

    foreach($table->find('tr') as $tr){
        $tdata[0] = $tr->find('td',0); //find the first td starts from 0
        $tdata[1] = $tr->find('td',1);
        $tdata[2] = $tr->find('td',2);
        $tdata[3] = $tr->find('td',3);
        $tdata[4] = $tr->find('td',4);
        $tdata[5] = $tr->find('td',5);

        $data[]= $tdata;
    }

        print_r($data);

?>
```

I at least expected to see the data from all the other cells

Comment: Please update the question to include `a variety of errors`. I would use domdoucment over `simple html dom`.

Answer (score 0):

Table column length is different, for this table use index 3 and 4 for getting Graphic Card name.

```
<?php
include_once('/simple_html_dom.php');


$html = file_get_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_EliteBook');

$table = $html->find('table.wikitable', 2);
$useIntel = array();

foreach ($table->find('tr') as $tr) {
    if (!$tr->find('td', 0))
        continue;

    for ($i = 3; $i <= 4; $i++)
        if ($tr->find('td', $i) && strpos($tr->find('td', $i)->innertext, 'Intel') !== false) {
            $useIntel[] = $tr->find('td', 0)->innertext;
            continue 2;
        }
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($useIntel);
```